# How can I find a meta user's associated accounts when the association system is down?

Tags: discussion, linked-accounts

The **accounts** tab of meta user profiles currently says:

> While the network is being migrated,
>   account assiciations to Meta have been
>   disabled.

I really need to find a meta user's other accounts. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible via the API. Go to (replace 147532 with the user's meta user ID):

> http://api.meta.stackoverflow.com/1.0/users/147532?type=jsontext

The find the `association_id`:

> "association_id": "96cd77c9-6749-488d-a80d-0b30a9587b60",

Then go to (replace 96cd77c9-6749-488d-a80d-0b30a9587b60 with the association ID):

> http://stackauth.com/1.0/users/96cd77c9-6749-488d-a80d-0b30a9587b60/associated?type=jsontext

The IDs of their various accounts will be listed.

Comment: your link requires the SO user ID, not the meta ID (tested with [my meta](http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/users/146482?type=jsontext) vs [my SO ID](http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/users/321973?type=jsontext))

Comment: @Tobias: Sorry, that was meant to be `meta.stackoverflow`. Fixed.

Comment: works now, +1ing